# Unity3D UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have anayltics in my Unity3D game and I realised that some Android devices throw the **UnauthorizedAccessException** when I am trying to create a folder on the device.

Have a look at the code that throws the exception:

```
static void SaveToCache(Entry entry, byte[] bytes) {
    if (entry.file != null) {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(entry.file);
        try {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            File.WriteAllBytes(entry.file, bytes);          
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Analytics.LogException(ex, "couldn't save to cache: " + path);
        }
    }
}
```

The code looks good for me, but perhaps I'm missing something... It does not throw on my test devices - I only have the stack trace from my analytics.

More relevant code is how I build the path:

```
static readonly char DirectorySeparator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;    

static string BundleFile(string id, string languageCode) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(BundlePath());
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("_");
    sb.Append(languageCode.ToLower());
    sb.Append(".json");
    return sb.ToString();
}

static string BundlePath() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(Application.persistentDataPath);
    sb.Append(DirectorySeparator);
    sb.Append("bundles");
    sb.Append(DirectorySeparator);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Please tell me if someone out there has similar issues. Can't I rely on *Application.persistentDataPath* ? Is there a better way to build the path for the cache files?

Comment: Can the user disable write permissions for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing a toolkit for handling persistent data paths on android. This checks for write access and even uses a fallback if disk space is running out.

[find the code here](https://gist.github.com/gering/f37082d8dd45a3ae4f2c)